# Securely posting from Fiddler 2.0 to ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http

Given: http://anyurl.com/Base/Processor/ is the base url to hit a controller action on Processor, I have no trouble using HTTP GET to pass values to the server using REST routes "/value" or form parameter "?value=value".

However, when I try to post placing the payload in the http request body, I cannot get the server to accept the input. I have tried several variations of the following:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: anyurl.com
Content-Length: 11
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

value=value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't specified the content type. Try setting the `Content-Type` header to `x-form-www-urlencoded`.

Comment: @BenFoster: Yes. I went back and with fiddler and took sample POST/PUT/GET/HEAD/DELETE to use as templates, this was one of the issues. I will vote you up but need you to post an answer to pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that the server understands how to process the POSTed content you need to set the `Content-Type` header. In your example this should be set to `x-form-www-urlencoded`.